# How to create list of all possible lists with n elements consisting of integers between 1 and 10?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a set of test cases for a project I'm working on, and I'd like to create all possible test cases and iterate through them (quick program, shouldn't take long). The test cases should all be a list of length 1-4 and each item on the list should be an integer between 0-10, inclusive. The first item on the list should be 0. The set of lists would then be:

```
[0]
[0,0]
[0,1]
[0,2]
[0,3]
...
[0,10]
[0,0,0]
[0,0,1]
[0,0,2]
[0,0,3]
...
[0,1,0]
[0,1,1]
[0,1,2]
...
[0,10,10]
...
[0,10,10,10]
```

This is what I have so far, but it's not outputting the correct lists:

```
test_list = [0]

for length in range(2, 5):
    while len(test_list) < length:
        test_list.append(0)
    for position in range(1, length):
        for digit in range (0, 11):
            test_list[position] = digit
            print test_list
```

Comment: Aren't the items between 0-10 ?

Comment: Yes, my mistake! Items should be between 0-10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A memory efficient one-liner :

```
import itertools
size = 4
for x in map(list, itertools.chain(*(itertools.product([0], *[range(11)]*i) for i in range(size)))):
    print(x)
```

You can modify 4 with any other list size :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre haha if you want… The one who downvoted this is maybe stupid or something…

Comment: @Labo yes, it works! I upvoted, but I'm new here and don't have enough reputation for it show up.

Comment: @Greg No problem, I'm glad I could help you.

Answer (score 4):

or you could generate the lists with a generator; this way you would not have the whole list in memory:

```
from itertools import product

def gen():
    yield [0]
    for i in range(11):
        yield [0, i]
    for i, j in product(range(11), range(11)):
        yield [0, i, j]
    for i, j, k in product(range(11), range(11), range(11)):
        yield [0, i, j, k]


for item in gen():
    print(item)
```

this seems pretty readable to me but is not extensible (in case you need longer lists) as other answers here.

therefore here the version where the length of the list is tweakable:

```
from itertools import product

def gen(length):
    for l in range(length):
        for tpl in product(range(11), repeat=l):
            yield (0,) + tpl

for item in gen(length=4):
    print(item)
```

this version now returns `tuples` and not `lists`. in case this matters you can surrout the return values with `list()`.

Comment: You can use the named repeat argument of product to make a clearer code, and also generalize it (look at my answer, it's almost the same, but in a one liner)

Comment: Eventually, I will need longer lists. Up to length = 10

Comment: You output [0] then (0,) and only tuples!

Comment: When l=0, product yields (,) so you don't need the yield (0,).

Comment: You can simply yield [0] + list(tpl)

Comment: @Labo sure, but i'd like to avoid creating unnecessary lists if that is not really needed for the caller. if feel that lists are overused; i try to use tuples and arrays whenever possible.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Python doesn't make any difference between arrays and lists.

Comment: @Labo: i disagree! but just to clarify: when i say `array` i mean [these `arrays`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/array.html). i prefer those than `list`s with just `int`s for example.

Comment: My bad, these are indeed different and very useful arrays. But I don't understand why you don't like lists and like tuples. There are only 16 bytes of size difference (and tuples are a little bit faster, but not editable). With arrays you may gain a factor of memory, but you lose what makes one strength of python : the int type which has no limit.

Comment: @Labo everything depends on the use case, of course! `list`s are perfectly fine most of the time, no doubt. and there are cases where they are the only option. `tuples` may be safer (because immutable) or necessary (as keys in `dict`s etc). but whenever i  need limited `int`s or an immutable collection, i will use anything but `list`s. and sometimes a `deque` is the thing to use. it's just that many people exclusively use `list`s - and that makes me say they are overused.

Comment: Tuples are hashable too! You can't put lists in a set. I totally agree with you although tuples are used quite frequently too.

Comment: @Labo i was arguing about the overuse of `list`s. i explicitly state that `tuple`s are suited as keys for `dict`s  (or values in `set`s - which is the same implementation afaik) because they are hashable. and as `product` returns a `tuple` here i see no need for futher conversion if there i no need for it.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `itertools.product` on lists of size 2, 3, 4 in a nested loop

```
import itertools

test_list = [0]
for i in range(1,4):
    args = [list(range(0,11))] *i
    test_list += [[0]+list(x) for x in itertools.product(*args)]

# display list
for t in test_list:
    print(t)
```

Comment: Your solution stores all lists in a list, which costs a lot of memory!

Comment: who downvoted almost all the answers? any justification?

Comment: I downvoted your answer because it consumes too much memory! You store the WHOLE list. With a length of 4 it is OK, but with a length of 6 it becomes huge.

Comment: I can print the results as you do, much easier. That won't consume that much memory.

Comment: The problem is that you store the complete list. Using the function at https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577504/, total_size(test_list) with lists of length 7 gives me 249825864 Bytes, so about 250 MB. For length 6, it is about 25 MB. Such a memory waste is not affordable in most cases.

Comment: another solution used `yield` for that purpose (it was downvoted too BTW)

Comment: The other solution uses yield to return tuples, which is not what OP requested.